# Response content-type text/html while expected application/json

Tags: json, mime-types, httpresponse, content-type

I have the same application on two different servers. On one server there is everything OK the application is loaded correctly. On the second server the application can't load. The error message is Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0. When I open developer tools in a browser I see that response content type header on the second server is text/html while on the first server is application/json what it should be. 
On both servers in IIS MIME Types is .json  application/json.
What else could block the corect content type on the second server?

Comment: Both servers are IIS? Same server version? Same code deployed?

Comment: Yes they are exactly the same

Answer (score 1):

Here is one of possible answers:
In our case it turned out that the cause was IIS setting, actually Application Pool setting. Instead of using Integrated, we had it switched to Classic.
When using Classic Application Pool in IIS, all JSON media type responses were converted automatically http/text.

Switching it back to Integrated Application Pool solved the issue.
Hope it helps somebody.
Radek

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it's caused by the same issue you're facing, but on our server we had to force the header to have it's content type as json to deal with something similar.

Thats the line of code we added:

```
header('Content-type:application/json;charset=utf-8');
```

.

```
  public function renderError($err){
   header('Content-type:application/json;charset=utf-8');
   echo json_encode(array(
       'success' => false,
       'err' => $err
   ));
}
```

Hope that can help somehow. :)