# Response to POST request has text/html Content-Type while I need application/json, while Chrome Dev Tools shows JSON response

Tags: json, python-requests, content-type

I'm using Python's `requests` module to make a POST request to a certain website. My goal is to get the response as JSON.
The issue: the `Content-Type` header of the response is `text/html`. Trying to parse it as JSON raises an error. Printing the content of the response gives me a bunch of convoluted html which I don't want.
However, on Chrome Dev Tools > Network, I can see the same POST request's response as a JSON object. Also, the `Content-Type` header of the response on Dev Tools clearly says `application/json`.
My goal is to force the `Content-Type` of the response to `application/json` in my Python script.
I tried the following:

- Set the header manually:

```
response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
response.json()
```

No luck.

- Set `Content-Type` and `Accept` to `application/json` in the *request*. This didn't make much sense but it was worth the try.
- Send my request data as `multipart/form-data` as it says in Dev Tools. No luck.

This is almost exactly the same issue as this question: [Response content-type text/html while expected application/json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42813206/response-content-type-text-html-while-expected-application-json), but that one was in a more specific context and the solution doesn't apply to me.

Thank you!

Comment: Can you share the URL?

Comment: @AndrejKesely Sure: https://services.liqahcorona.ma/DemandeSuivi/SearchAttestationfr

Comment: In fact, of more relevance is the URL for the POST request (sorry), which is: https://services.liqahcorona.ma/DemandeSuivi/CheckAttestationFr?Length=12

Answer (score 1):

I have same issue as your After 10 hour research I solve my problem by using below code

```
import requests
import json

url = ""
headers = {"content-type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8"}
payload = {}
r = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=json.dumps(payload))
```

Hope, This will Help you